# How to Exclude the special characters and allow the spanish/english alphabets?

Tags: javascript, regex, string-formatting

I am working on a Spanish site, i have a search on that site and we are not allowed to send these special character in the keyboard(! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + - = [ ] \ { } | ; ,' : " ./<>? ). In the English version of the site we were doing some thing like this `term.replace(/\W|_/g," ");` in java script. This allow all the alphabet(both upper and lower case), and numbers and filter out those special characters.

In the same way how should i send all the English/Spanish alphabet,numbers and exclude those characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the regex to the following should work:

```
/[^\wáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚñÑ]|_/g
```

Or as MДΓΓ БДLL pointed out in comments:

```
/[^\wáéíóúñ]|_/gi
```

The `^` at the beginning of the character class negates it, so this could be read as "match all characters that are NOT in `[a-zA-Z0-9_áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚñÑ]`, and also match `_`".

As a side note, you can simplify your current regex to `/[\W_]/g`.

Comment: You can simplify the character class by making it case-insensitive. `/[^\wáéíóúñ]|_/gi`

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL, I wasn't sure if that would work for the Spanish characters, thanks!

Comment: +1 and just a note, but while `/[\W_]/g` is better, because you don't need the alternation, it is actually one character longer in length than the OP's original :)

Comment: @F.J :) sorry for being a pesky pedant

Comment: i searched búsqueda and (this with modified code term.replace(/[^\wáÁéÉíÍóÓúÚñÑ]|_/g," ")) and this is what i am seeing 'b squeda'. It is still replacing spanish character. i don't want the spanish charactes to be replaced.

Comment: @pushya, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq398/) that works for me on Chrome and IE9, give that a try in your browsers.

Comment: @F.J When i save the file(.jsfile) that  above mentioned code live in to UTF -8 then it worked for me. Thx for the help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088834/issues-with-the-accented-characters/11088875#11088875