# Issues with the accented characters

Tags: javascript, encoding, special-characters

I have a search box on my site and i need to replace all the Spanish characters that user types in to equivalent English alphabets. I have coded which is shown below. This is not working when i plug in it to the my Project and even when create a simple html page which coded same. My page is using `<meta charset="utf-8" />`. This is working fine when i created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KJAy3/. This is how it it is show in the debugger[image]

What am i doing wrong? What kind of encoding i am supposed to us? This Replace method is triggered before the form submit.

```
function encodeSearch(term){

term=term.replace("á","a");
term=term.replace("Á","A");
term=term.replace("é","e");
term=term.replace("É","E");
term=term.replace("í","i");
term=term.replace("Í","I");
term=term.replace("ó","o");
term=term.replace("Ó","O");
term=term.replace("ú","u");
term=term.replace("Ú","U");
term=term.replace("ñ","n");
term=term.replace("Ñ","N");
return term;
```

}

Comment: Ensure that the file that contains this code is saved in `utf-8` encoding

Comment: The encoding of the source file itself matters as well. Are you saving it as ascii, by chance?

Comment: Are you remembering to save the result of `encodeSearch()`?

Comment: @Esailija how will i know that the file is saved as utf-8? this script is in a .js file and the file goes in a page that has charset of utf8 as i shown above.

Comment: @pushya Yes the page has `utf-8` but since you have not saved the file in `utf-8` the characters are showing wrong. You need both for it to work. When you save a file like this, you can select what encoding to use: http://i.imgur.com/qaPFb.png It might depend on your editor.

Comment: @Esailaja. Thanks it worked. i never heard of this kind of solution before. How you save the file in a speciific format makes a difference WOW!!!. A small Question this file when uploded to Server in QA/PROD. it will still remains a UTF-8 file as i check in to repository right correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you used `<script type="application/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="yourfile.js"></script>"`? (Assuming your file is saved as utf-8, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use those special characters in HTML, it may be an idea to use this String `replace` method for all special characters:

```
[somestring].replace(/[\u0080-\u024F]/g,
                      function(a) {
                        return '&#'+a.charCodeAt(0)+';';
                      });
```

It will convert all special characters to numeric html entities and prevent the need to type all those characters in your javascript, e.g.

```
 'ñíóúü¡¿'.replace(.replace(/[\u0080-\u024F]/g,
                      function(a) {
                        return '&#'+a.charCodeAt(0)+';';
                      });
  //=> result
  // &#241;&#237;&#243;&#250;&#252;&#161;&#191;
```